# Choosefile widget: "Error in FUN: object 'Type' not found"

Tags: r, shiny, widget, reactive

I am building a shiny app that would allow me to select a data file using a widget "choose file" and "select file" as well as plotting a bar graph using geom_bar object of the library ggplot2. The plot consists of a bar graph representing the revenue ("Revenue") per type of operation ("Type") and has a different colour of the bar for each type.
When I run the app I get the following error : Error in FUN: object 'Type' not found.

I have changed aes by aes_string but it doesn't change anything. I have also tried to add inherit.aes = FALSE in the geom_bar object. I made sure the data I use is saved as data frame.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#user interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Shiny File Upload"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "file",
                label = "Upload the file",
                multiple = TRUE),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "header", label = "Header"),
      radioButtons("sep","Seperator", choices = c(Comma=",", Period = ".", Semicolon = ";")),


      # Select variable for y-axis
      selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                  label = "Revenue:",
                  choices = "Revenue",
                  selected = ""),

      # Select variable for x-axis
      selectInput(inputId = "x", 
                  label = "X-axis:",
                  choices = "Type",
                  selected = ""),

      # Select variable for color
      selectInput(inputId = "z", 
                  label = "Color by:",
                  choices = "Type",
                  selected = "")
    ), 
    # Outputs
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("input_file"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "Barplot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server function required to create the scatterplot
server <- function(input, output) {


  #Dispays the content of the input$file dataframe
  output$filedf <- renderTable({
  if(is.null(input$file)){return()}
   input$file
  })
  output$filedf2 <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(input$file)){return()}
    input$file$datapath
  })
  #Side bar select input widget coming through render UI()
  output$selectfile <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$file)){return()}
    list(hr(),
         helpText("Select the files for which you need to see data and summary stats"),
         selectInput("Select", "Select", choices=input$file$name)
         )
  })


      # Create the scatterplot object the plotOutput function is expecting

  output$Barplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = input$file, aes_string(x = input$x , y = input$y, fill = input$x)) + geom_bar( stat ="identity") + coord_flip()

  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I expect to have a bar plot with revenues bar for the 14 type of operation, with bar color differing depending on the observation.
I expect to be able to select the data I want and get this bar plot for this dataset.

Comment: `input$file` is not the dataset contained in your file. You have to read the file to a dataframe, e.g. `read.csv(innput$file$datapath)` if it is a CSV file. See the example in `?fileInput`.

Comment: Thank you @StéphaneLaurent, I added read.csv but I still have this error.